# Preenchimento automático com select woocommerce checkout

Tags: select, input, woocommerce, checkout

Tenho o seguinte código para gerar um select e trazer os valores dentro dos options:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'cliente_woocommerce' ); 
function cliente_woocommerce( $checkout ) 
{ 
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM tab_clientes" );
$options  = array( '' => __('Selecione o cliente') );

// Loop through the data query results
foreach($results as $result) {
    $options[$result->nome] = $result->razao_social;

}

echo '<div id="cliente_woocommerce"><h2>' . __('Cliente') . '</h2>';

woocommerce_form_field( 'cliente', array( 
    'type' => 'select', 
    'class' => array('cliente form-row-wide'), 
    'label' => __('Campo de Teste (Cliente)'), 
    'options'   =>  $options,
), $checkout->get_value( 'cliente' ) );

woocommerce_form_field( 'nome', array( 
    'type' => 'text', 
    'class' => array('nome form-row-wide'), 
    'label' => __('Razão Social'), 
    'default'   =>  '',

), $checkout->get_value( 'nome' ) );
woocommerce_form_field( 'cnpj', array( 
    'type' => 'text', 
    'class' => array('cnpj form-row-wide'), 
    'label' => __('CNPJ'), 
    'default'   =>  '',


), $checkout->get_value( 'cnpj' ) );


echo '</div>';
```

com o seguinte script:

```
       <script>
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#cliente').change(function() {
                $('#nome').val( $( this ).val() );
            });
            $('#nome').change(function() {
                $('#cnpj').val( $( this ).val() );
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Quando seleciono o cliente, o campo #nome (razão social - na tabela = razao_social) aparece com o valor correto, porém o valor se repete dentro de CNPJ.

O que estou fazendo errado?